# Not a valid format string - info which language is wrong

Tags: android

I use `getString(R.string.xxxx, "Test", "Test2")` in my code and get the the error "**Format string xxxx is not a valid format string...**"!

So far so good, but how can I see **which language** is wrong?
I have **over 30 langauges** and don't want to check each file by hand every time.

Is there any way to find the wrong language file/files?

Comment: Are you using the numbered arguments style: `%1$s`, `%2$d`? Or just `%s`? Because that could be the reason. And if that's the case, then you'll probably need to update all of the languages.

Comment: I use %1$s and %2$s! I have already found the problem in one of the languages, but I need always to open every language file and check the syntax manually. Lint seems knows the problem and so it knows the file with the wrong translation, but it does not show it :-(

Comment: @chrisonline have you found solution how to know which locale file contains error?

Comment: No, sadly no solution yet. ☹️

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
   DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    Resources r = getResources();
    Configuration c = r.getConfiguration();

    Locale[] loc = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
    for (int i = 0; i < loc.length; i++) {

        c.locale = loc[i];
        Resources res = new Resources(getAssets(), metrics, c);
        String s1 = res.getString(R.string.app_name);
        Log.d("LOCALE",loc[i].getDisplayCountry()+" : "+ s1  );
    }
```

In android studio:

> Right-click the strings.xml file, and select Open Translations Editor.

[image]

[More info in developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/translations-editor.html)

Comment: Yes this would be a workaround to see all resources in a list. Is there no native way inside Android Studio to see which is wrong?

Comment: Yes of course I know the Translations Editor, but I have also to check every language by myself which one is wrong. I have meant if there is a shortcut or log exactly which language LINT have found wrong.